# regexp file name

Tags: php, regex

We have file name like `hello-world-part-2.html`

Help me please to build pattern to extract `file name before part` and part `number` in php.

In above example we need to get

```
$matches[1] = 'hello-world';

$matches[2] = '2';
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @Johnsyweb php. GolezTrol yes i've tried, in other case i wouldn't've asked here. i know it's very simple, but i stucked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the language you use but the pattern should be the following:

```
(.*)-part-(\d+)\.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it worth to use regular expression for this task?

Why don't you just simply split the string?

### Regular Expression

#### C#

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("hello-world-part-2", @"([^\x2D]+)")) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

#### Output

1. hello
2. world
3. part
4. 2

Here here you'll know that:

- **Iteration #1** = *hello*
- **Iteration #2** = *world*

So you just simply concatenate both:

```
string filename = match[0] + "-" + match[1];
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $pattern = '/(?P<filename1>[^\-]+)\-(?P<filename2>[^\-]+)\-part\-(?P<number>\d+)(?P<extension>[^$]+)/x';
    $input = "hello-world-part-2.html";

    preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

    $filename = $matches["filename1"][0] . "-" . $matches["filename2"][0];
    $number = $matches["number"][0];
    $extension = $matches["extension"][0];

    echo "Filename: " . $filename, "\n";
    echo "Number: " . $number, "\n";
    echo "Extension: " . $extension, "\n";
?>
```

#### Output

- **Filename:** *hello-world*
- **Number:** *2*
- **Extension:** *.html*

### Split

#### C#

```
string longFileName = "hello-world-part-2";
var parts = longFileName.Split(new char[] {'-'});

int position = 0;

string filename = null;
string number = null;

foreach (String part in parts) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            filename += part;
            break;

        case 1:
            filename += "-";
            filename += part;

            break;

        case 3:
            number += part;
            break;
    }
    ++position;
}

Console.WriteLine(filename);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

#### Output

- **filename:** *hello-world*
- **number:** *2*

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $input = "hello-world-part-2.html";
    $array = split("-", $input);

    $filename;
    $number;


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        switch ($i) {
            case 0:
                $filename .= $array[$i];
                break;

            case 1:
                $filename .= "-";
                $filename .= $array[$i];

                break;

            case 3:

                $str = $array[$i];
                $str_array = split("\.", $str);

                for ($j = 0; $j < count($str_array); $j++) {
                    switch ($j) {
                        case 0:
                            $number = $str_array[$j];
                            break;
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    echo $filename, "\n";
    echo $number, "\n";
?>
```

#### Output

- **filename:** *hello-world*
- **number:** *2*

By the way, You better specify the programming language on your tags, so it would be easy for us to help you.